# $h_n=3h_{n-1} -2,\ (n\geq{1}); \ h_0=1$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Solve the nonhomogeneous recurrence relation.
$h_n=3h_{n-1} -2,\ (n\geq{1}); \ h_0=1$

so, $h_n-3h_{n-1}=-2$

I'm doing this by generating functions

$$g(x) = h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+h_3x^3+...$$
$$-3x\ g(x)=  -3h_0x-3h_1x^2-3h_2x^3-3h_3x^4-...$$

adding these two equations we get,

$$g(x)(1-3x) = 1+(h_1-3h_0)x+(h_2-3h_1)x^2+(9h_3-3h_2)x^3+...  $$

so each of the $(h_n-h_{n-1})$ are equivalent to $-2$. Pluggin that in, we get

$$g(x)(1-3x) = 1-2x-2x^2-2x^3-2x^4...  $$
add $-3$ to both sides,

$$g(x)(1-3x) -3=-2+2x+2x^2+2x^3+2x^4+...   $$ 
$$= -2(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...) $$
$$= -2\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)   $$

isolating $g(x)$, we get
$$g(x)= -2\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{1-3x}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{3}{1-3x}\bigg)  $$

$$g(x)= -2\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{1-3x}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{3}{1-3x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1-x}{1-x}\bigg)  $$
$$=\bigg(\frac{-2+3-3x}{(1-x)(1-3x)}\bigg) = \frac{1-3x}{(1-x)(1-3x)}$$

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

and $h_n = 1$

Comment: Do partial fractions decomposition to write $g(x)$ as a linear combination of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-3x}$, then expand each of these as a geometric series. (If that's enough to solve your problem, try doing the work and submitting it as an answer to this question so that we can check your work.)

Comment: How about expanding what you have now into a product of two power series?

Comment: Also: 1) Your recursion relation should be valid for $n\geq 1$, not $n\geq 2$. (Otherwise the initial instance of the recursion is $h_2 = 3h_1 -2$, which leaves $h_1$ undefined.) 2) You've got a small but important typo: If $h_n=3h_{n-1}-2$, then $h_n-3h_{n-1}=-2$ _not_ $h_n-3h_{n-1}=2$. That propagates through your answer to the very end, and leads to a much simpler answer.

Comment: Thank you @semiclassical, that $n\geq{2}$ is a typo

Comment: Don't know if this is suitable but how about using Akra-Bazzi's theorem ?

Comment: @ semiclassical, I multiplied $\frac{-1}{1-3x}$ by $\frac{1-x}{1-x}$ to get a common denominator and wound up with things cancelling. $\frac{2-1+x}{(1-x)(1-3x)}$ $= \frac{1-x}{(1-x)(1-3x)} $$= \frac{1}{1-3x}$  Is that correct?

Comment: @semiclassical, nevermind I lost changed a + to a - in there.

Comment: @semiclassical, so I did the partial fraction decomp and got, $g(x) = \frac{-1}{1-x}+\frac{2}{1-3x}$ $= -(1+x+x^2+x^3...)+2(1+3x+(3x)^2+(3x)^3+...)$ $=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [-1+2(3^n)]x^n$  and therefore, $h_n= -1+2(3^n)$

Comment: it is $$h_n=\frac{1}{2}(3^n+1)$$

Comment: Take a look at your recursion relation and its first few values. You have $h_0=1$, $h_1=3(1)-2=1,$ $h_2=3(1)-2=1,\cdots$. That suggests that your generating function should be _very_ simple. PS: I mentioned in an edit of an earlier comment that you've got a typo in your answer, so if you haven't fixed that you should do so.

Comment: @semiclassical, okay I see that my $h_n$ is wrong, but I cannot seem to find where I went wrong... I'm going to modify the original post with my work and maybe you can check it. It's difficult for me to use latex correctly in the comments

Comment: Wow okay yes, I changed the $(n\geq1)$ but I also mistakenly wrote positive 2 instead of -2 at the very beginning as well. Thank you @semiclassical

Comment: That all works now. Now you can simplify that answer without having to even do partial fractions(!)

Comment: Motto: $$\text{Always look for fixed points.}$$ Hence the shortcut: $$h_n-1=3(h_{n-1}-1)$$ which yields $$h_n-1=3^n(h_0-1)$$ and, in the present case, $$h_0=1$$ hence, for every $n$, $$h_n=1$$

Comment: @Did thank you I will keep that in mind for the future! But the point of this homework problem was to practice the generating functions method. I had realized immediately that plugging in the first few n's kept giving me 1. But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @Bellatrix1106 "But the point of this homework problem was to practice the generating functions method" Ah, OK. (Not that it matters much but maybe you could explain this feature more clearly next time?)

Comment: You can also obtain @Did's shortcut under the motto of "take consecutive differences" by introducing $h_n'=h_{n+1}-h_n=3h_{n-1}'=0$ for all $n\geq 1$. That kind of approach is helpful when your inhomogenous term is a polynomial in $n$ rather than a constant.

Comment: @Semiclassical Very true (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Besides your own method based upon generating functions, let me show you another one similar to the well-known method of "variation of constants" for 1st order ordinary differential equations.

First, drop the inhomogeneous part and study the homogeneous problem $g_n = 3 g_{n-1}$ with an unspecified initial condition $g_0 = c$. In this case, the solution is very quick to obtain: $g_n = 3^n c$.

Next, "vary the constant" $c$ by replacing it with $c_n$ and assume $h_n$ to be of the form $3^n c_n$ (i.e. the $g_n$ obtained above with $c$ replaced by $c_n$). From the defining formula of $h_n$ you will get $3^n c_n = 3^n c_{n-1} - 2$, which leads to

$$c_n = c_{n-1} - \frac 2 {3^n} = c_{n-2} - \frac 2 {3^{n-1}} - \frac 2 {3^n} = \dots = c_0 - \frac 2 {3^1} - \dots - \frac 2 {3^{n-1}} - \frac 2 {3^n} = \\
c_0 - \frac 2 3 \left(1 + \frac 1 3 + \dots + \frac 1 {3^{n-1}} \right) = c_0 - \frac 2 3 \frac {1 - \frac 1 {3^n}} {1 - \frac 1 3} = c_0 - 1 + \frac 1 {3^n} .$$

To find out $c_0$ use the initial condition: $1 = h_0 = 3^0 c_0$, so that $c_0 = 1$, whence you get $c_n = \frac 1 {3^n}$, which in turn implies $h_n = 3^n c_n = 3^n \frac 1 {3^n} = 1$.

With a result similar to the uniqueness property for inhomogeneous linear differential equations with constant coefficients, it can be shown that your problem has a unique solution (if any), therefore the solution $h_n = 1$ is the only one of your problem.